# How to output a cumulative list from Wordpress API in Ionic infinite scroll

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, wordpress-rest-api

I am new to angular and Ionic and I am trying a practical approach of learning by working with sample projects from GitHub.

I have downloaded this project: https://github.com/enappd/ionic4-wordpress-integration and I have modified the WordPress URL where I am pulling the data from.

Currently, the load more infinite scroll seems to replace the output results with the next page results instead of combining the results of the second page with the first page.

I am currently attempting a solution by modifying the home.page.ts like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  url: string = '#######################'
  items: any = []
  page: any = 1;
  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public Router: Router,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public loadingController: LoadingController
  ) {

    this.loadPost(this.url, this.page, true);
  }
  async loadPost(url: string, page, showLoading) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading Your posts'
    });
    if (showLoading) {
      await loading.present();
    }

    const route = this.url + 'wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
    // set pagination
    if (!page) {
      page = '1';
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var concat;

      // check if url already has a query param
      if (url.indexOf('?') > 0) {
        concat = '&';
      } else {
        concat = '?';
      }

      this.http.get(route + concat + 'page=' + page)
        .subscribe(data => {

          if (showLoading) {
            loading.dismiss();
          }
          this.items = data;
          console.log(data);
          resolve(this.items);
        },
          error => {
            if (showLoading) {
              loading.dismiss();
            }
            reject(error);
            this.presentToast(error.error.message)
          })
    });
  }
  doRefresh(event) {
    this.loadPost(this.url, 1, false).then(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    }).catch(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    });
  }

  loadMore(event) {

    this.page++;

    this.loadPost(this.url, this.page, false).then(items => {

      let length = items["length"];

      for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            this.items.push( items[i] );
          }

      console.log(this.items);


      event.target.complete()
    }).catch(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    });

  }

  /*
  loadMore(event) {

    this.page++;

    this.loadPost(this.url, this.page, false).then(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    }).catch(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    });

  }
  */

  async presentToast(msg) {

    let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom',
      cssClass: 'normal-toast'
    });

    toast.present();

  }

  goToPostDetails(post) {
    this.Router.navigate([`post-details/${post.id}`]);
  }
}
```

Please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `this.items = data;` in `loadPost()`. If `this.items` exist you should merge two arrays instead of replacing it and then remove:

```
let length = items["length"];
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  this.items.push( items[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on lonwi's answer, I realised I was not suppose to be modifying the `loadMore()` and therefore reverted to using this for the `loadMore()`...

```
loadMore(event) {

    this.page++;

    this.loadPost(this.url, this.page, false).then(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    }).catch(() => {
      event.target.complete()
    });

  }
```

Furthermore in `loadPost()`, I have replaced the line `this.items = data;` with...

```
let length = data["length"];
          for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            this.items.push( data[i] );
          }
```